# Fixing invalid xml characters

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following element in my dictionary:

```
d = {'Name': 'La vie r\xc3\xaav\xc3\xa9e de Gaspard'}
```

Printing the name or inserting it directly into my database works fine:

```
>>> print d['Name']
La vie rêvée de Gaspard
```

However, if I add this to my xml, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: Also how do you add it to XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'La vie r\xc3\xaav\xc3\xa9e de Gaspard'` is a bytestring, so you need to decode it to unicode as the exception suggests.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> d = {'Name': 'La vie r\xc3\xaav\xc3\xa9e de Gaspard'}
>>> e = etree.Element('root')
>>> e.set('name', d['Name'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 746, in lxml.etree._Element.set (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:42970)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 547, in lxml.etree._setAttributeValue (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:19025)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1395, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:26485)
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

>>> e.set('name', d['Name'].decode('utf-8'))
>>> etree.tostring(e)
'<root name="La vie r&#234;v&#233;e de Gaspard"/>'
```

The same applies to setting an element's text attribute:

```
>>> e = etree.Element('root')
>>> e.text = d['Name'].decode('utf-8')
>>> etree.tostring(e)
'<root>La vie r&#234;v&#233;e de Gaspard</root>'
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Would there be a way to detect if this is required by a way other than a `try: d['Name'] except ValueError: d['Name'].decode('utf-8')` ? For example a ternary operator if it can be decoded to utf-8.

Comment: @David542 it depends on your situation. If you're sure that all text will be utf-8 or ascii you can just decode anyway. If text could have an arbitrary encoding then maybe use a library like chardet to determine the encoding.